# Run cron at startup only if time is between 12pm and 1pm

Tags: cron, archlinux, raspberry-pi3

On my raspberry pi 3 with Arch Linux installed, I have a cron that is setup to run at 12pm everyday. This works fine so long as the pi is powered on at 12pm. The problem is if the pi is switched on at 12.03pm, for example, the event never fires.

Is there a way I can force a check at startup to see if the current time is later than 12pm and before 1pm, so that I can have the event fire at then?

A long shot but thought maybe someone may be able to help me out?

Adam

Comment: See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488669/how-do-i-activate-cron-command-once-within-specific-time-frame)

Answer (score 0):

You can use and create another job like this

Write in console terminal

```
crontab -e
01 13 * * * /usr/bin/somecommand
```