# How do i activate cron command once within specific time frame?

Tags: cron, archlinux, cron-task, raspberry-pi3

Basic information about my system: I have a music system where people can schedule songs to start and end at a specific time.

OS: Arch linux

It sets two crons at the moment. One lets say at 1.50 (start time with a command like "play etc") and another set at 3.20 (end time with a command like "end etc").

My setup works perfectly and i can end delete schedules etc etc but i now noticed an issue! If i set the above times and turn the system off (My system is a raspberry pi) and turn back on at lets say 2.00 and i missed the 1.50 deadline, the music doesnt start (obviously) and i want to try make it so no matter what time i turn it on within a range lets say: 1.50 - 3.20 it will start the play command. But it will run the command once!

I looked around and the commands i got was like:

```
0 1.50-3.20/2 * * * your_command.sh
```

But thats to run every 2 hours. I want it to run once only between these times?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a PHP file and load the page on reboot then do its work and redirect back to such and such.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an additional cron job which starts a script on every reboot. For instance, you could add a line like this to your crontab:

```
@reboot /home/pi/startplayback.sh
```

Your startplayback.sh script should check if current time is within the desired period and run the desired command if it is. For example the code below will print PLAY! if the script is run between 1:50 and 3:20. You could replace **echo 'PLAY!'** by **run WHATEVER**

```
#!/bin/bash

current=$(date '+%H%M')
(( current=(10#$current) ))
((current > 150 && current < 320 )) && echo 'PLAY!'
```

P.S. Don't forget to make your script executable `sudo chmod +x startplayback.sh`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [the at command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at) and its utilities.

```
SYNOPSIS
     at [-q queue] [-f file] [-mldbv] time
     at [-q queue] [-f file] [-mldbv] -t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]
     at -c job [job ...]
     at -l [job ...]
     at -l -q queue
     at -r job [job ...]

     atq [-q queue] [-v]

     atrm job [job ...]

     batch [-q queue] [-f file] [-mv] [time]
```

[at](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm) is good for scheduling one time jobs to be run at some point in the future.  It maintains a queue of these jobs, so you can use it to schedule things with a great variety of different time specifications.

Cron is in my opinion a scheduler for jobs that are to be repeated over and over.

So a quick and dirty example for you:

```
echo 'ls -lathF' | at now + 1 minute
```

As expected you will see a job to be run in one minute.  Try atq to see the list of jobs.

When the job is done, output will be mailed to your user by default.